# Can we use username and password directly to authenticate kerberized solr

Tags: solr, kerberos

I am able to authenticate kerberized solr by using keytab. But not able to authenticate by using simple username and password directly in java client using solrj.

I have tried using SolrHttpClientBuilder.CredentialsProviderProvider. But this is not working. Is there any way we can authenticate using direct username and password like basic authentication.

```java
CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("xczc", "zxczx#123");
AuthScope scope = new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, null);
provider.setCredentials(scope, credentials);
Registry<AuthSchemeProvider> authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeProvider>create()
                                .register(AuthSchemes.KERBEROS, new KerberosSchemeFactory(true)).build();
CloseableHttpClient httpclient1 = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry)
                                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();

SolrClient client = solrClientBuilder.withHttpClient(httpclient1).build();
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please review [minimal, complete, reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) help page and update your question accordingly. If this is your attempt, then also include any errors you have encountered.

Comment: There is a default setting in the JVM `security` config that blocks a pop-up for interactive Kerberos user/password input. If you override that setting, you get the pop-up.

Comment: But be aware that Kerberos is about **serious** security. While hard-coded clear-text passwords (like your example) are not serious. You can't do that kind of silly stuff with Kerberos, by design.

Comment: And SPNego (Kerberos over HTTP) does not let web client libs -- with tons of vulnerabilities -- mess with the user credentials.

Comment: You might want to read HTTPCLIENT-1625 and notice that you are of of luck.